# OnItemClickListener and OnClickListener not working for ListView

Tags: android, listview, scroll, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener

I have used a Custom ListView and I am displaying some data using the same ListView. 
 
 When I click on the List View item, the **onClickListener** is not getting called. I am not able to select any list item.

**Layout Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/imgProperty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:padding="3dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
        android:focusable="false"/>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="75dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_image"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:text="property"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvprice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgProperty"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvCity"
    android:text="Price" 
    android:focusable="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Adapter code:**

```
 public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

 ArrayList<Propety> PropertiesArray;
private LayoutInflater Inflater;


public CustomListAdapter(ArrayList<Propety> PropertiesArray) {  

   this.PropertiesArray=PropertiesArray;

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return PropertiesArray.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return PropertiesArray.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

     if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlistview, parent, false);
        }


        final Propety ListArray = PropertiesArray.get(position);

       TextView tvPropertyName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCity);
       tvPropertyName.setText(ListArray.getName());

        TextView tvPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvprice);
        tvPrice.setText(ListArray.getPrice());

       ImageView imgProperty = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
       imgProperty.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);


       convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "view clicked: " + ListArray.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    return convertView;
}

}
```

**ListView code:**

```
 ListView propertylistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
CustomListAdapter customlistview=new CustomListAdapter(PropertiesArray);
propertylistview.setAdapter(customlistview);
```

**ListView XML:**

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/customview"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:textAlignment="center" >
```

**custom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surface"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtangle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="115dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"
    android:text="" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/customview"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:textAlignment="center" >

</ListView>

<view
    android:id="@+id/customview"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    class="com.example.samplebuapp.CustomCompass" />

<view
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
    class="com.example.samplebuapp.CustomView" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/listview"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:focusable="false">
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Even scrolling is not working.

I am unable to figure out why is this happening? Am I missing out something?

Any help in resolving this is appreciated.

Comment: maybe this can help: http://www.thepcwizard.in/2012/09/android-creating-custom-listview-for.html

Comment: It seems that the touch events are not propagating to the ListView. Is there any thing in your layout file along with the ListView that could prevent the touch from being propagated?

Comment: I am displaying the ListView along with other Custom Views and surfaceView. Please see the custom.xml

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following will do the job in your case.

```
ListView propertylistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview); 
    propertylistview.setOnItemClickListener(  myListViewClicked ):

        OnItemClickListener myListViewClicked = new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Clicked at positon = " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        };
```

Dont forget to remove the following from the CustomAdapter

```
  convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

         Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "view clicked: " + ListArray.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Ninja. Thats not working. I am displaying the ListView on a surfaceView. Displaying ListView on a SurfaceView causes any problem??

Comment: You use `myListViewClicked` before you've declared it..?

Comment: By assigning OnItemClickListener to a variable first (then pass into setOnItemClickListener), it mysteriously solved my problem. Then after that when I do it without having to assign to variable then it still works.)

Answer (score 3):

If the touch events are getting intercepted inside the cell layout, in the layout for your custom cell, set 
`android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on the top level layout of your cell.  For me, it was too much of a pain to add xml attributes to every individual view.

Note that this can also be set in code:

`cell.setDescendantFocusability(FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);`

I also tried this with a ListView inside a cell, and I had to override onTouchEvent to get it to work:

```
public class NoTouchListView extends ListView {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the simple code that solved my problem, and method view.setOnClickListener be within my custom adapter

```
    view.setFocusable(false)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your list row layout once :

> layout or any view should not be `android:clickable="true" and
>   android:focusable="true"

if it is there just delete and run the application again.

Answer (score 1):

Even I was having the same problem, I am having checkbox, did the following to masker itemClickListener work,

Added the following properties to the checkbox,

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:clickable="false"
```

and ItemClickListner started working.

For detailed example you can go through the link,

http://knowledge-cess.com/android-itemclicklistner-with-checkbox-or-radiobutton/

Hope it helps Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

For TextView you should also use

```
android:textIsSelectable="false"
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextIsSelectable