# ListView OnItemClickListener is not working

Tags: android, android-listview, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener

**possible duplicates**

> [ListView OnItemClickListener Not Responding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367936/listview-onitemclicklistener-not-responding)
>
> [OnItemClickListener and OnClickListener not working for ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437673/onitemclicklistener-and-onclicklistener-not-working-for-listview)

I have added `onClickListener` to root layout of list item and according to the answer to [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367936/listview-onitemclicklistener-not-responding) question and [this](https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/listview-doesnt-respond-to-onitemclicklistener/) post I made same root layout `focusable=false`. Tried from both, java as well as xml.

But still no luck, `OnItemClickListener` is not responding to item click events.

please have a look at following code,

`list_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/todoly_selector_list_item">
    
    [..Some code..]

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the `getView` of adapter has following code,

```
if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(
        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    
    /*
     * I need to have this, if I remove this line OnItemClickListener works,
     * no otherwise.
     */ 
    convertView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    
    convertView.setFocusable(false);
    
    [..Some code..]

}
```

What I am doing wrong here? or Is it not possible to do so?

Comment: Perhaps it'd be good to explain *why* you're saying you need an `OnClickListener` on the list item's root? That's effectively what an `OnItemClickListener` is for, so why would you need both?

Comment: I am wrinting a multi select adapter as in [this](http://dharmendra4android.blogspot.in/2012/10/multi-selection-listview-example-in.html) post. Addition to that is, I have a `mIsMultiSelect` attribute which can be used for toggling the multiselect mode.
multiselect will starts on item long press and selection will be based on item click. 

but as the problem, when I add `OnClickListener` to root layout of item then `OnItemClickListener` as well as `OnItemLongClickListener` stops responding..

Comment: In that case, you should set the mode in the `OnItemLongClickListener` and then based on that decide what should happen in `OnItemClickListener` - you shouldn't have to need another `OnItemClickListener` on the row items for that.

Comment: In that way the selection logic will not go in the `Adapter`, I just made it work,
`getView` of adapter is now having this code.

`if (mIsMultiSelect) {
            convertView.setClickable(true);
            convertView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        } else {
            convertView.setSelected(false);
            convertView.setClickable(false);
        }`
and `onClick` is `public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mIsMultiSelect) {
                v.setSelected(!v.isSelected());
            }
        }`