# ListView with custom adapter is not selectable

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have ListView with custom adapter. Listview is not clickable but setOnItemLongClickListener worked properly. ListView row.xml is below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivTourImage"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblTourName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Tour Name" />

<RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBarTourStarCount"
            style="@style/hotelRatingBarSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:focusable="false"
android:isIndicator="true"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:stepSize="1.0" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"> 

<TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblPlace"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Place" />

<TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="#b6fffa12"
            android:text="Price"
            android:textColor="#ff4770ff" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/adult_icon_16x16" />

<TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblAdultCount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Adult" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/children_icon_16x16" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblChildCount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Child" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/meal_icon_16x16" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblMealCount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Meal" />
</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

ListView usage:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabTourList"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <ListView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/listViewTourAnounce"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

How to make my listview clickable? Please help me

Comment: Try to add *android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"* to the top ViewGroup of your row view ( the LinearLayout)

Comment: I answered a similar question [here][1]. Hope will help.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437673/onitemclicklistener-and-onclicklistener-not-working-for-listview/18539885#18539885

Comment: Thanks for answers but none of theese is solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Try by this code It may Help you.

```
   ListView roomsList
    List<String> roomlistdata;
    roomlistdata = new ArrayList<String>();
     roomsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.roomsList);
    roomlistdata.add("your data");
    ArrayAdapter<String> str = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                                    getBaseContext(),
                                                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                                    roomlistdata);
                                            roomsList.setAdapter(str);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long arg3) {
        view.setSelected(true);

        String UserSelected = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
        ...//contests_listView is a array list
    }
}
```

Comment: `position` is int ! why you write `String currentPosition = position` ?

Comment: The item click event is not fired, so he will never enter to this method.

Comment: I think problem inside xml, but i don't know where  is

Comment: setOnItemClickListener method fires but selected row not changed backcolor