# How to select row in custom list view android?

Tags: java, android

I am new Android developer. I have a custom `ListView` with image, title, description. When I click row in custom list view, there is no action onclick.

Please advise how to solve this issue?

Comment: 1st piece of advice, post your code and any errors.

Comment: Please see this url question for list view that i implemented http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437673/onitemclicklistener-and-onclicklistener-not-working-for-listview

Comment: @ChrisAlan are you saying this is a duplicate?

Comment: This is just for example for OnItemClickListener for custom list view not working.

Comment: some one suggest me android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

Answer (score 3):

first set onItemClickListener to your listview

and then perform your action in onItemClick method.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) { 

       //perform your action here

}
```

Comment: if list view contain button,image,title ,description such like product page  than this will not work.why?please advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, position, id)  {

    });
```

if you have Button in  list_item.xml put `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in the LinearLayout or RelativeLayout you have

[ListView Tips & Tricks #4: Add Several Clickable Areas](http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/11/23/listview-tips-tricks-4-add-several-clickable-areas/)

https://syedasaraahmed.wordpress.com/2012/10/03/android-onitemclicklistener-not-responding-clickable-rowitem-of-custom-listview/

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add the list view like this: ListView lv and it assigns lv as the ListView constructor, becoming referenced to ListView it as you have set it.

Then Set this:

> lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
>
> @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<"your adapter view goes here"> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) 
>       { 
>       //perform your action here
>        } <

You have called on the list view method to execute the message of the setonitemclicklistener method in the list view class which as the constructor you would set up I.e list view referenced as lv.  It all ties together