# onClickitemlisner doesn't work

Tags: android

I work on an android project. I use a `ListView` in `Fragment` name TableauDeBordFragment and it works but the problem is that `setOnItemClickListener` doesn't work this is my code of my `Fragment`.
I try to add `tableauDeBordListview.setClickable(true)` but still doesn't work.

```
public class TableauDeBordFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
public static String SERVEL_URL = "http://192.168.2.120:8081/access-control-web/rest/services/attendance";
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
ListView tableauDeBordListview;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tableau_de_bord, container, false);
    tableauDeBordListview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.tableaudebordlist);
    DownloadJSON downloadJSON = new DownloadJSON();
    downloadJSON.execute();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), URLStorage.getDefaults("URL", getActivity()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    tableauDeBordListview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),position+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
   public class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            URL theURL = new URL(SERVEL_URL);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(theURL.openConnection().getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

            String jsonStr = reader.readLine();
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                Attendance attendance = new Attendance();
                JSONObject jsonAttendanceItem = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject jsonMonthlyWorkedHourItem = jsonAttendanceItem.getJSONObject("monthlyWorkedHour");
                attendance.setMonthlyWorkedHour(new Duration(jsonMonthlyWorkedHourItem.getLong("seconds")));
             Log.d("emna", attendance.getDailyWorkedHour().getSeconds() + "");

                JSONObject jsonEmployeeItem = jsonAttendanceItem.getJSONObject("employeeDto");
                Employee employe = new Employee();
                employe.setFirstName(jsonEmployeeItem.getString("firstName"));
                employe.setLastName(jsonEmployeeItem.getString("lastName"));
                employe.setPhoneNumber(jsonEmployeeItem.getString("phoneNumber"));
                employees.add(employe);
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        ArrayAdapter<Employee> adapter = new TableDeBordCustum(getActivity(), employees);
        tableauDeBordListview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What are the views existed on listView..?

Comment: it seems that tableauDeBordListview is empty during onCreateView.. so, there's no item to be clicked

Comment: Is list contains data?

Comment: refer following link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437673/onitemclicklistener-and-onclicklistener-not-working-for-listview

Comment: the view  is tow textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding listview in a background task!

Doing something after your listview is populated will work!

Example code below;

```
 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  
{ 
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ob) ; 
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customview_completedxml_listview, null ) ; 


 TextView txt = ( TextView ) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_fordisplayingdata) ; 
  txt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
         Toast.makeText(ob, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
  txt.setText(recieved_Array[position]) ; 

  return v ; 
}
```